# How to retrieve a report from HP Performance Center

Tags: jenkins, alm

How to retrieve a report  from HP Performance Center

We run regular, scheduled jobs in Performance Center.  These are scheduled to run via the Performance Center API.  I want to then have a scheduled job in Jenkins that will pull one of the reports from the job and save it somewhere where I can then post a link to it in Slack, or email the link, or somehow get it to the group that needs the info.
Now, I have been able, via the API, to in fact get the report, which is in a .zip file.  But this just displays it,as binary characters in the Jenkins console window.  I cannot figure out how, in the Jenkins Groovy script, to push that .zip file to some external location.  It also, for some reason, does not show up as an artifact when I click on the job in Jenkins.
I don't have to do this via the API, I would be open to using a Jenkins plugin if one exists.  But I would like to know how to do the API method if possible as I have no admin rights and Jenkins and have to deal with another group in the company via service tickets to get this done.  That being said, is it possible to see somewhere in Jenkins, as a lowly user, what plugins are installed?

Comment: Have you tried "Archive the artifacts" post-build action for artifact publishing? I think this is a built-in post-build action

Comment: Well, this is a pipeline build so i have put this at the end of the job:

archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'Report.zip'

But I never get any archives in the job.  Just the binary representation of the .zip file.

Comment: Can you show how you fetch the report from PC?

Comment: I use a Get in Postman:

http://<server>/LoadTest/rest/domains/<domain name>/projects/<project name>/Runs/437/Results/3418/data.  This returns the same binary as I mentioned above, then I do a "Save Response" and save it to a file, a .zip file.

Comment: Was that helpful?

Comment: Sorry, was in the middle of nowhere, without internet connection. What I meant to ask is how do you do this in Jenkins? Do you use Groovy script? If so - just write the response from PC server to a file inside Jenkins job's workspace and feed the path to archiveArtifacts step - this should allow you to publish your artifact propertly